# Laravel 5.8 .env.testing file is not working

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

I created a .env.testing file with my credentials, everything the same as .env besides a different table name for the database.

I tried `php artisan config:clear` which deletes the cached config file in `bootstrap/cache/config.php` and it broke the database connection. If I re-cache the file by running `php artisan config:cache` the cached file is back, but without the credentials in the .env.testing file. When I rerun PHPUnit, it connects to the wrong DB, the DB name that is stored in .env not .env.testing.

Is this for real? Did the latest Laravel release break test environments?

Here is what the docs read: (found here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/testing)

"You are free to define other testing environment configuration values as necessary. The testing environment variables can be configured in the phpunit.xml file, but make sure to clear your configuration cache using the config:clear Artisan command before running your tests!

Also, you may create a .env.testing file in the root of your project. This file will override the .env file when running PHPUnit tests or executing Artisan commands with the  --env=testing option."

***UPDATE***

I finally was able to override the database that is stated in the .env by adding the database override in the phpunit.xml file; the .env.testing is still not working. The docs are misleading at the least.

Comment: I deleted this because I thought I was just being an idiot and solved the problem, but nope. I still haven't solved this issue. Any one out there have custom .en.testing files working?

Comment: How / where do you tell the Laravel test-suite to use .env.testing instead of .env (apart from clearing the config cache)? From your question it sounds like you expect it to work out of the box, but from other questions here I can read this is not the case. It's perhaps worth to ensure that first, the other problems just seem to describe an after-effect of thtat.

Comment: Are you using PHPStorm?

Comment: Try these docs https://hub.docker.com/r/chilio/laravel-dusk-ci it should help you on enabling local and remote tests.

Comment: For other devs who have similar issue, I tried all above but didnt work. instead I used `php artisan config:clear --env=testing` (not config:cache) ha suddenly it loads `.env.testing` file and works fine.

Answer (score 54):

I was having this same problem with Laravel v5.6. I set up a `.env.testing` file with a different username, password, and database but my tests were always running in the main `.env` database.

It looks like you need to specify the test environment when running the config cache command. After running this command, it worked as described in the docs:

```
php artisan config:cache --env=testing
```

Comment: If I run `php artisan config:cache --env=testing`, then the local server will use the `testing` environment. But if I run `php artisan config:cache --env=local` then phpunit will use the .env instead of .env.testing

Comment: Note that as soon as you run ```php artisan config:cache``` again (without env flag) you'll be back to using regular environment until you do ```php artisan config:cache --env=testing``` again. It's whatever is currently in ```bootstrap/cache/config.php```.

Comment: For other devs who have similar issue, I tried all above but didnt work. instead I used `php artisan config:clear --env=testing` (not config:cache) ha suddenly it loads `.env.testing` file and works fine. I'm using Laravel 10

Answer (score 15):

This is what worked for me:

In `phpunit.xml` I had to define `<env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>` inside the `<php>` block to make PhpUnit load `.env.testing` instead of `.env`

---

It seems like the Laravel docs are wrong and `.env.testing` is not hard-coded anywhere in Laravel or PhpUnit, it reads the environment file for whatever `APP_ENV` is specified in `phpunit.xml`. You could even rename this to `.env.phpunit` or anything else if you define it in `phpunit.xml` in this format: `<env name="APP_ENV" value="phpunit"/>`

Comment: This was the right answer for me, as you say the Laravel docs are missleading here. My "testing" environment is called "local" so none of the other suggestions were working, changing the other names to "local" too _did_ work! Thanks

Comment: Oh man can't believe I missed this file. My `APP_ENV` in `phpunit.xml` was set to an empty string. What is weird is I was calling my console commands with the `--env=testing` argument but I guess `phpunit.xml` overrides this (when calling artisan command from a unit test). Thanks for this!

Answer (score 10):

I was having the same issue with Laravel v7. Had my hands in my hair for quite some time, but I found a workaround.

The .env.testing was a lost cause for me. I never got it to load, so I just put all the variables within phpunit.xml. To make the testing environment (`php artisan test`) actually load those variables, I had to do this:

First I had to set `APP_ENV` in phpunit.xml to `force="true"`:

```
<php>
    <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing" force="true"/>
    <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
    <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
    <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
    <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
    <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
</php>
```

Then I had to run `php artisan config:clear`, NOT `:cache`. When I ran `php artisan config:cache` it actually would not work. Probably because it caches the env once and never loads the new settings based on the different environment.

Comment: The `php artisan config:clear` worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: `config:cache` clears the cache and then repopulates it. This is why the accepted answer includes the `--env` flag.

Answer (score 9):

You need to set APP_CONFIG_CACHE variable in phpunit.xml to avoid testing and local configurations overwrites each other.

```
<server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
<server name="APP_CONFIG_CACHE" value="cache/config-testing.php" force="true"/>
```

Comment: I can't believe I've searched so long for this answer. Do you have any idea why it seems to work for other people? Because IMHO it is not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Laravel only reload environment variables if config file `bootstrap/cache/config.php` is not cached.

Since Laravel uses same config file for every `APP_ENV` type (production, local, testing), when you run `php artisan config:cache` and change your environment, a new config.php is created with your new variables, and this will work right until you change to other environment.

To avoid run `php artisan config:cache` every time you change your environment, you can isolate your cache config file at env level by using `APP_CONFIG_CACHE`.

Comment: For me the path was "bootstrap/cache/config-testing.php". Maybe this will help somebody.

Comment: 2023: it still works! I had to use "env" in place of "server"

Comment: Thank you! That's the only thing that worked for me, after 2 days of searching!

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the variables defined in `phpunit.xml` is overriding the variables defined in `.env.testing` file, not the other way around as we all expect.

I recommend keeping only `APP_ENV` in `phpunit.xml` and then cloning `.env.testing` from current `.env`. And it will work as expected.

**phpunit.xml**

```xml
<php>
  <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
  <!-- Remove all others and define them in .env.testing -->
</php>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was my issue, as soon as I removed the other `<env name=` it worked :D

Answer (score 2):

In order to run **.env.testing** in test runs only and to run **.env** in default behavior. You will need to execute:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit.bat // For windows
./vendor/bin/phpunit // For Linux
```

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

When you use a local docker container, make sure you don't set the "env_file" key in docker-compose.yml to point to your .env file (or have it overwritten with an environment key). These container-level environment variables take precedence over the values loaded by Laravel (i.e. from .env.testing).

So **don't** do the following in your docker-compose.yml:

```
phpfpm:
  env_file: .env
```

or

```
phpfpm 
  environment:
    APP_ENV: "testing"
```

or otherwise unset them before running tests:
`unset DB_CONNECTION OR_OTHERS && php artisan config:cache --env=testing && php artisan test`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and it turns out none of the other answers were on point at all.

I'm on Laravel 9 for this, so it is possible that my answer is too far into the future, but this question is the one that pops up on Google when I search for "laravel .env.testing not working"

Here's how I fixed it:

1. Restored `Tests/TestCase.php` to the "new project" content (it contained some crud)

   It's a short file, so I can paste it here too:

   ```php
   <?php

   namespace Tests;

   use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

   abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
   {
       use CreatesApplication;
   }
   ```
2. Make sure to extend the right class in your tests

   - ✅ YES: `extends Tests\TestCase`
   - ❌ NO: `extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`
3. Override the `setUp` method

   ```php
    private string $emailDomain;
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->emailDomain = env('EMAIL_DOMAIN');
    }
   ```

And make damn sure you call `parent::setUp` too.

Then everything works as described in the manual and there's no need to touch the `phpunit.xml` file. Just leave it be.

Extra credits: my `phpunit.xml` file used `<server ...>` in the `<php>` section, but it should use `<env ...>` instead, like the one provided by Laravel by default.

Comment: As expected, I got a minus 1 :) Wouldn't be Stack Overflow otherwise.

Comment: I am giving it an upvote now sorry that happened!

Answer (score -1):

What does your `.env.testing` look like?

is your environment set to `APP_ENV=testing`?

When I do tests and I do not have that and only have my database details in the file it does not work but when I make a carbon copy of the original .env file and edit the env to testing mine works.

Comment: I run a dev server, which uses the .env file and connects to a local mysql server. In the same time, I would like to run unit tests. I created a .env.testing, and defined a :memory: sqlite connection in it. For some reason, the .env is used during the testing, as if .env.testing would not be there.

Comment: Yes I read the question :) I was asking is your `APP_ENV` set in that file.

Comment: It was: `APP_ENV=local`. I changed it to `APP_ENV=testing`, but the error is the same

Answer (score -1):

If you are likely using phpstorm,then,

go to settings of your phpstorm or  press Ctrl + Alt + S.

then selectt Languages & Frameworks ->PHP ->Test Frameworks
Under Test Runner tab, click Default configuration file and select (by clicking the folder icon) the path of your project's PHPUnit.xml file.

it will make all your changes in the xml file take effect.Then create the .env.testing file, create your preferred DB config variables for test and running your tests again!

Comment: I am not using phpstorm. I run the local server and the tests from the terminal

Comment: I am using VIM for life!